# Delete rows without unique id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with the following columns: ClientID, Amount, etc. The problem is that some clients have two or more rows with `Amount = 0`, and I want to remove these rows. I've searched some information but only found with unique identification.

**Sample input**:

| ClientID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| QER1 | 531 |
| QER2 | 521 |
| QER3 | 0 |
| QER4 | 231 |
| QER2 | 0 |
| QER1 | 0 |

**Expected Output**:

| ClientID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| QER1 | 531 |
| QER2 | 521 |
| QER3 | 0 |
| QER4 | 231 |

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, can't you add a 'where Amount > 0' statement in your query?

Comment: @Jocohan Yes, the problem is that the table is too large for doing this individually

Comment: @matdlara don't do it individually, do it based on the value of `Amount` ? `DELETE FROM table WHERE Amount = 0;` It can help if you have an index on the Amount column.

Comment: @Martin some clients have Amount = 0 and they aren't repeated

Comment: so... max(Amount) for each clientID?  Is there a date/time that gives us an order  maybe we can assign a row_number() over (partition by TimeField desc) and then limit to only row 1?  Could you just sum(Amount) Zero has no effect on the sum...  Is there a PK on this table?

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/ might help

Comment: How does the table look exactly?

Comment: @matdlara you should clarify what *exactly* you are trying to achieve, in your question. Your question states "I want to remove these rows" meaning the rows where Amount = 0 but then you mention repeated rows so? Do you only want to remove rows where amount= 0 if there's a larger number for each clientId? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM <table_name> t1 
INNER JOIN <table_name> t2 ON t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID AND t2.Amount > t1.Amount
WHERE t1.`Amount` = 0  ;
```

This will only remove rows if they have Amount = 0 and there is another amount with the same ClientId that is more than zero.

- If a ClientID appears only once nothing is deleted.
- If a ClientID has a maximum Amount of zero nothing is deleted.

This second point may cause you issues, you can have ClientID with two rows of Amount = 0. If this is a problem you can [Create a unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/3536236) which will clear this for you at the structural level:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table
ADD UNIQUE INDEX unqiueness (ClientID, Amount);
```

Your problem is that if you have two identical rows (ClientID and Amount = 0) then there is no unqiue identifier to distinguish and only remove *one* of those rows, this is not something we can fix at the query level (ie by running queries on the data) but is a core structural problem with your database design. You should have a unique index id for each row, typically called a Primary Key.

Indexing your Amount column is recommended. Also adding a unique row identifier (Primary Key) is also **highly recommended**.

You can [view this SQL in action here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xrN4ct3mQPeEdKFPKfD755/0) .

Answer (score 0):

You could `INNER JOIN` on the same table to select the clients who have the same `CliendID` and then delete those who have an `Amount` of `0`

```
DELETE t1 FROM clients t1
INNER JOIN clients t2 -- Join on the same table
WHERE 
 t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID AND
 t1.Amount = 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the inner join actually achieves here? This seems just the same as delete if amount = 0;